# Reeb graph of the tilted torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, morse-theory

Reeb graph :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reeb_graph

some pictures: http://www.math.brown.edu/~banchoff/Beyond3d/chapter3/section08.html

The Reeb graph of an upright torus, which I'll call "a vertical torus", of the height function has a loop since there exists a horizontal slice resulting in two separate connected components.

The Reeb graph of a toppled over upright torus, which I'll call "a horizontal torus", of the height function doesnt have a loop.

Certainly a slightly tilted vertical torus has Reeb graph with loop by inspection.

Is this true for all angles of tilt leaving only the perfectly horizontal torus without a loop in its Reeb graph?

Comment: If it matters, the Reeb graph for the height function of a horizontal torus _is_ a loop (because each non-critical level is a pair of concentric circles).

Comment: I thought each critical level is an annulus? level sets as we move up in height: starting from a circle, then an expanding annulus then a contracting annulus, ending at a circle??

Comment: The torus is a _surface_ like the rubber of an inner tube, not the solid torus. ;)